# cannot import name 'Bootstrap5' from 'flask_bootstrap'?

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-5, flask-bootstrap

I am trying to import Bootstrap5 from flask_bootstrap in my Python code on a Mac M1 using Python3. However, I get an import error saying that the name Bootstrap5 cannot be imported from flask_bootstrap. Here's the code snippet:

```
 from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify

 from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap5
```

and I get this error

**cannot import name 'Bootstrap5' from 'flask_bootstrap'**

I can import bootstrap without any issues, but not Bootstrap5. What could be causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I am having the same error message after I deploy on a cloud server - but I do not get the error on my Mac when I test locally using the development server (using a virtual environment locally)

Answer (score 2):

follow the instructions on https://bootstrap-flask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basic/#installation

```
pip uninstall flask-bootstrap bootstrap-flask
pip install bootstrap-flask
```

Comment: this is the first thing I tried. Doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I've found the fix! In your requirements.txt, manually delete the line:

```
Flask-Bootstrap4==4.0.2
```

Yes, Bootstrap-Flask does need this, but it will install it on its own. Removing that line and re-uploading requirements.txt to the cloud server solved this issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

According to Bootstrap documentation, [basic usage](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

def create_app():
  app = Flask(__name__)
  Bootstrap(app)

  return app

# do something with app...
```

Import Bootstrap instead if Bootstrap5

Comment: bootstrap works, I know, but I need bootstrap5